# How to detect and avoid infinite loops?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, infinite-loop

I want to make sure that my web application is performance wise and will not make any performance problems. When I searched, I found that one of the most common problems related to the performance issue is the "infinite loops" problem.

I want to ask:

Where should I begin to check that my code never causes infinite loops?

Are there any articles, advices, instructions, examples? I will be grateful.

ex:

May this code cause an infinite loop?

```
public static IEnumerable<SubjectNode> ReadSubjectNodes(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (XmlReader xrdr = new XmlTextReader(fs))
        while (xrdr.Read())
            if (xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xrdr.LocalName == "subject")
                yield return new SubjectNode(xrdr.GetAttribute("id"), xrdr.GetAttribute("name"), xrdr.GetAttribute("short"));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe put some huge upper limit i.e. `int ReadCount = 100000; while(xrdr.Read() && ReadCount-- > 0)`

Comment: This is most likely not what you're looking for, but the general problem of finding out whether a program enters an infinite loop or finishes (["halting problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) is unsolvable.

Comment: What exactly is the code doing? Are you going to output this to the user or is this a behind-the-scenes execution?  If you are outputting results to a user you could get the first 10 -> display the results -> then have a navigation to go from one page to the other each time only iterating the next 10 files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, AFAIK that code *won't* cause an infinite loop - it is not recursive, and an `XmlReader` from the file-system will eventually run out of data. It might be *long running*, though. In some cases, adding a sanity check may help - this could be a counter, or a check against the time. For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<SubjectNode> ReadSubjectNodes(string filePath)
{
    int safetyCheck = 10000;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    using (XmlReader xrdr = new XmlTextReader(fs))
        while (xrdr.Read()) {
            if(--safetyCheck == 0) throw new SomeTypeOfException();
            ... more code
        }
    ... more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.but are there any general advices should  i take care?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to deterministically pre-determine whether a loop will run infinite times, except for the ones which have a compile-time defined number of iterations and don't alter the iteration counter in their body.

Just write **good code** which is not prone to infinite looping: inspect the conditions inside the while loops and think about a case in which they *might* cause infinite looping. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted here has an exit condition: When the `XmlTextReader` reaches the end of its stream. Therefore, it's not an infinite loop.

That's really what you need to do to prevent these: make sure every loop has a condition which will cause it to exit. It's much easier to do when writing the code than reviewing it later.

Answer (score 2):

Infinate loops occur when you are looping until a parameter is met ( a while loop ), but it is possible that the while clause is never satisfied to exit the loop. And hence it goes on forever.

It is also possible to cause a recursive loop, by where you call a function from within itself (or similar), where it will constantly call up a function, but never get closer to exiting.

`while (xrdr.Read())`, is fine as long as `.Read()` is invoking the moving to the next element automatically. At which, as your xrdr is not an infinite source, it will eventually reach the end and exit.